# Given $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$. Find an $x= [s \ \ t]$, in $\mathbb R^2$ whose image under $T$ is $b$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused with this question. Do I have to row reduce?

[image]

Comment: Try to answer this:  what exactly is it asking you to do?  Do you know what the image of a function (transformation) is?

Comment: Why do you think you have to row-reduce?  What is it exactly that you think you have to row-reduce?

Comment: You just need to solve the linear equation system $Ax = b$, i.e. $-3x_1 - 3x_2 = 12$, $7x_1 + 5x_2 = -24$, $-x_1 + x_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve

\begin{align*}
-3x_1-3x_2&=12\\
7x_1+5x_2&=-24\\
-x_1+x_2&=0
\end{align*}